# Get distinct category columns with multiple subcategory columns mapped in table

Tags: sql-server, query

I have 2 tables, category and subcategory, this query

```
select C.Description,s.Description
from category C
inner join SubCategory S on C.CategoryID =S.CategoryID 
where  C.IsActive=1 and S.IsActive=1
```

gives the following output:

[image]

But my output has to be as follows:

[image]

Comment: That can be accomplished on the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Take a look at the example below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp ( Description VARCHAR(100), SubDescription VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #temp ( Description, SubDescription )VALUES ( 'Patient Assignment', 'Peds' );
INSERT INTO #temp ( Description, SubDescription )VALUES ( 'Patient Assignment', 'Peds2' );
INSERT INTO #temp ( Description, SubDescription )VALUES ( 'Patient Assignment', 'Peds3' );
INSERT INTO #temp ( Description, SubDescription )VALUES ( 'Patient Assignment', 'Peds4' );

INSERT INTO #temp ( Description, SubDescription )VALUES ( 'Patient Assignment1', 'Peds' );
INSERT INTO #temp ( Description, SubDescription )VALUES ( 'Patient Assignment1', 'Peds2' );
INSERT INTO #temp ( Description, SubDescription )VALUES ( 'Patient Assignment1', 'Peds3' );
INSERT INTO #temp ( Description, SubDescription )VALUES ( 'Patient Assignment1', 'Peds4' );

WITH Temp
AS (
    SELECT
        Description,
        SubDescription,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Description
ORDER BY Description ) rownumber
    FROM #Temp
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Temp.rownumber = 1 THEN Description ELSE '' END Description,
    SubDescription
FROM Temp;
```

But I'd prefer doing that in the application layer.

Comment: Thank you for the timely help

Comment: Anytime! 
@Revathi, If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rrequested result set can not be possible to get through sql. Sql server matches row from source to destination and build a result set. To achieve this task put row group on first column at application end.

Answer (score -1):

```
select C.Description,s.Description
from category C
inner join SubCategory S on C.CategoryID =S.CategoryID 
where  C.IsActive=1 and S.IsActive=1
```

[image: output]

Comment: It doesn't seem the desired result.